# Setting up Google Calendar API

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API in one of my projects. To do so, I need to set up OAuth access in the Google API console.
But when creating the consent-form (which is required to use OAuth), I get a meaningless error message:

[image]

The translation is as follows:

> A problem occured. Please check your data and try again . If you have
>   not given any details, the problem may solve itself . In this case, we
>   recommend that you wait and try again later.

I have set the E-Mail address and project name. The optional fields were left blank.

So far I have not been able to solve the problem. I tried to wait for hours/days. I tried three different browsers. I also tried to contact Google support. All without success.

Comment: Did you try again recently? Are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it again. I got the same meaningless error.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this with a new project. :/

Comment: What do you mean by consent form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trying, this is the solution:

- Create another Google account
- Using your old account, add the new account as an owner to your Google API project in the console
- Log in with your new user account and accept the invitation
- Create the OAuth consent form with the new user account

I have no idea WHY this worked, but it did.